# NgRx Store does not change value when the previous and current value are same

Tags: angular, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using NgRx Store, I subscribe to the change to store for the feature. The store does not detect changes when the previous and current values are the same.

```
this.rootStore.pipe(select(someState.getStatus)).subscribe(someValue => {
      console.log(someValue);
    });

onLoad: someValue = 1;
OnAction 1 => onStateChanged: someValue = 2;
OnAction 2 => onStateChanged: someValue = 2; (this action is reported but do not record it with above subscription).
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of primitive value in Action payload, you could use an object, so after reference change selector will be notified

Answer (score 1):

This is intended, a selector is memorized. It will only execute when its input parameters are changed for performance reasons.

Brandon recently did a talk at ng-conf about selectors, which I highly recommend [Building Sub States w/ NgRx Selectors | Brandon Roberts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXuSDiLmcN0)

Answer (score 0):

When using `select`, what it does behind the scenes is just a `map` + `distinctUntilChanged`.

So if your value is a number, and you update your store with the same number, it won't fire again.

Comment: is there any way to get around that? I am still trying a way with what @tim pointed out below, with no luck yet.

Comment: I guess you could use `map` instead of `select` but my guess is that this reveal a flaw within your architecture because you shouldn't need to be warn when a value changes to the exact same value so I'd advise against it.